# Undefined array key "subject" in contact.php on line 18

Tags: php, forms

I would like to send to my email the details of the users, but its not submitting the information to my mail box. How must I code it?

I tried to fix the local server, but its still failing to send, please help me on this. Thank you very much.

How can I fix the submit button?

```
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$first_name     = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name     = $_POST['last_name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$select_price   = $_POST['select_price'];
$select_service   = $_POST['select_service'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];

if(trim($first_name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
}  else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
```

Comment: you can check for existence of a key in an object using the function `isset($_POST['subject']);`

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you stripped the code, so the error on line 18 refers to

```
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
```

Double check that you do have an input named 'subject' on your page.

Comment: I think i need to post my form maybe coz i don't understand something here.